# neo4j get values that match a criteria

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm working on a neo4j query trying to return a node that has a total ownership of 1 (representing 100%). So I'm summing the ownership of a node. My query to get the sum of ownership works correctly and is as follows:

`match (o:owner)-[:mineral_interest_owner]->(w:well)
return sum(o.ownership)`

So then I try to use that in an expression :

`match (o:owner)-[:mineral_interest_owner]->(w:well)
return sum(o.ownership)
case
when sum(o.ownership) = 1
then w.name
else "None"`

and get this error:
`Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 's': expected 'l/L' (line 3, column 3 (offset: 78))
"case"
   ^`

Is this something that I need to use APOC for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from your immediate question, your data model seems to need improvement. The `ownership` property should *not* be on the `owner` node, since that would mean that the owner has the same exact ownership percentage for all wells in which s/he has an interest. Instead, the `ownership` property should be on the `mineral_interest_owner` relationship -- which would allow all `ownership` percentages to be different.

Assuming that you incorporate the above data model improvement into your DB, this query should return all `owner`/`well` pairs where the owner owns 100% of that well.

```
MATCH (owner:owner)-[i:mineral_interest_owner]->(well:well)
WITH owner, well, SUM(i.ownership) AS pct
WHERE pct = 1
RETURN owner, well;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm new to the fun land of oil and gas leasing so figuring it out. I will incorporate these changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate and then use the `where`:

```
MATCH (o:owner)-[:mineral_interest_owner]->(w:well)
WITH w, 
     sum(o.ownership) AS cnt WHERE cnt = 1
RETURN w
```